# Data visualization: comparing two segments of a bipartite time series

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, dataset, multiple-comparisons

Hopefully, this question will make sense to someone.

I have a multi-valued continuous time series:

$(x, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4...y_n)$, where $x$ is the time axis.

This time series can be divided into 2 contiguous segments of equal length:

$(x, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4...y_n)$ for $0 < x < t_1$
$(x, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4...y_n)$ for $t_1 < x < t_2$

where $[0, t_1]$ is a period of same length as $[t_1, t_2]$

My question is:

What would be the best way to **visualize** the differences between the 2 segments?

To make things less cluttered and more feasible in some kind of 2D chart or graph, it is fine to assume the series are $(x, y_1, y_2, y_3)$ series.

Comment: Maybe some kind of lattice plot? Or stacked lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question "what would be the best way to visualize the *differences* between the 2 segments" is not clear because it does not specify the if you'd like to see the difference between time, between series, or between both. And the $n$ in $y_n$ actually matter here as well. If $n$ is reasonably big then off-the-shelf trellis plot should be suitable, but if it's too big you may need to tweak the trellis plot to show more compact expressions like [Sparklines](http://www.bissantz.de/site_images/tufte/sparklines.jpg) or to integrate some interactivity like user-controlled animated slide show.

**To emphasize synchronicity:**

One can overlay two series on top of each other, labeling which one is pre/post. For multiple series, you may create many of these plots and panel them together.

[image]

```
time <- 1:150
T <- 149
start <- 10
y1Pre <- start + c(0, cumsum(rnorm(T)))
y1Post <- start + c(0, cumsum(rnorm(T)))

##########

ymin <- 0
ymax <- max(c(y1Pre, y1Post))

plot(time, y1Pre, type="l", col="#aaaaaa", 
     ylim=c(ymin, ymax), xlim=c(0,155), ylab="y1", lwd=2, axes=F)
lines(time, y1Post, col="#22222290", lwd=2)
axis(side=1)
axis(side=2)
text(152, y1Pre[150], "Pre", adj=0)
text(152, y1Post[150], "Post", adj=0)
```

**To emphasize deviation from norm:**

To show how much the data in each segment deviate from the norm (here I use grand mean), drop line is a good approach. If you lay out the lines well, you can even overlay them together. Compounded with the skill of small multiples, you can create some high-density plot like [this one](http://informationdesignmdippold.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/good-id-1.jpg).

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(4,4,4,0))

grandMean <- mean(c(y1Pre, y1Post))

plot(time, y1Pre, type="n", ylim=c(ymin, ymax), ylab="y1", axes=F, main="Pre")
segments(time, grandMean, time, y1Pre, col="#43a2ca")
axis(side=1)
axis(side=2)
plot(time, y1Post, type="n", ylim=c(ymin, ymax), ylab="", axes=F, main="Post")
segments(time, grandMean, time, y1Post, col="#43a2ca")
axis(side=1, lab=c(150, 200, 250, 300), at = c(0, 50, 100, 150))
```

**To emphasize the absolute difference:**

If how much the data at $i^{th}$ time differ from each other is your main interest, then it's also possible to derive the difference of post-time minus pre-time and just plot the difference.

[image]

```
y1Diff <- y1Post - y1Pre

plot(time, y1Diff, type="n", ylim=c(min(y1Diff), max(y1Diff)), ylab="y1Post - y1Pre", axes=F)
segments(time, 0, time, y1Diff, col="#fc8d62")
axis(side=1)
axis(side=2)
```

Either way, I think panel (or trellis) graph is the way to go. It can often be confusing to throw more than 4-5 lines onto the same graph if the individual line matters. (One may, of course, throw a couple million lines onto a frame to show some general patterns.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, even though my question was not precise enough. I like the difference approach you illustrated.

Comment: @Laurent You're welcome. Feel free to post another question once you have solidified your objectives of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start of a visual example; you'd have to play with the labels and so on;

```
library(lattice)
x <-1:10
x2 <- rep(1:5,2)
y <- rnorm(10)
seq <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5))
xyplot(y~x2|seq, layout = c(1,2))
```